# Не работает register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
elif m.text == "Погода":
    def pogoda():
        try:
            place = m.text
            observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
            w = observation.weather
            temp = int((w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]))
            weath = w.detailed_status
            answer = "В географическом объекте " + m.text + " сейчас " + weath + \
                     ". Температура " + str(temp) + "℃."
            bot.send_message(m.chat.id, answer)
        except BaseException:
            error = "Указано неверное название географического объекта."
            bot.send_message(m.chat.id, error)
            return

    def p1():
        mesg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Напиши мне название географического объекта")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, pogoda)
    p1()
```

Comment: Так и не понял работу register_next_step_handler. Самое интересное что бот до некоторого времени работал. Не знаю почему

Comment: Что означает «не работает»? Что происходит вместо работы?

Comment: TypeError: a.<locals>.pogoda() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Логично предположить, что функция-хандлер должна принимать объект с новым входящим сообщением, а ваша функция pogoda почему-то ничего не принимает

Comment: Если я указываю у погоды 'message' то мне нужно указать 'message' и у p1. Как тогда ее вызвать если нет значения 'message'?

Comment: Я не понял о чём вы говорите, ничего у p1 указывать не надо, нужно всего лишь принять один аргумент в функции pogoda

Comment: Да и в общем-то само существование функции p1 не имеет смысла, вы создаёте функцию и сразу же вызываете её, но ведь можно просто сразу выполнить нужный код без его заворачивания в функцию

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Лучше опишу что мне нужно. Мне нужно чтобы при вводе пользователем "Погода" пользователь должен будет ввести название города к примеру. И уже с этой переменной мне нужно проводить действия. Мне непонятно как запросить этот ввод. Иначе в pogoda() передается m.text "Погода"

Comment: Замените `def pogoda():` на `def pogoda(m):`